# Print exact copy of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

Trying to achieve the goal of printing selected page's element ONE-TO-ONE - the exact same way it looks on the page.

What did I try:

- printElement() plugin.
- moving element to a new window:

  var printwindow = window.open();
  $(printwindow.document.body).html($('.contentwrap').html());

In both cases I needed to create separate styles (media='print') and/or new classes. At the same time - forms values were not copied to a new window.

My content is way too dynamic, populating data from ajax and data attributes on fly. Design of content is also based on JS.

Applying special styles and re-doing JS code - is NOT the way I want it to be. =)

I'm looking for a solution what makes EXACT copy of the element, ready to be printer and not be dependent on the browser print settings, styles/scripts adjustments.

It better be some kind of a screenshot =), letting client to download it as jpeg/pdf.

Any ideas?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `clone()`? I'm not sure it'll handle form values but should handle data attributes.

Comment: @MarttiLaine: clone() wont handle JS effects and grab all styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use: $('selector').clone(true) it will clone your selector and event handlers too.  By default clone is set to false and does not clone the event handlers

Comment: (true) really helps to grab handlers. But still need to create a separate style as media='print'. I guess this is the only possible way to handle printing on such elements. =)